# Unable to push the image to Firebase Storage and Display in app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

Please help! I am unable to push the photo to the Firebase Storage and consequently can't display in my app. This code is reference to the Udacity Firebase in a Weekend Course.
I want to push the selected photo to the firebase storage and display in my app.
The first picture shows the chat activity, 2nd picture shows intent to the picture gallery when the picture icon is clicked, and third picture shows the result where it fails to push the selected photo to firebase storage and also doesn't display in app.
I want to push the selected photo to firebase storage and display in the chat section

Link for the official documentation for upload the image to firebase storage -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?authuser=0

I tried the official documentation code but it also doesn't work

Link for the course which i followed -> https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud0352/lessons/fab5bf81-cfe5-4071-9afe-b6eb324a6257/concepts/27c52d47-50cd-4be1-8d3d-95e3fccebda5

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
    private static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER =  2;
    private FirebaseStorage mFirebaseStorage;
    private StorageReference mChatPhotosStorageReference;`
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
    
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    
        mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");
        mChatPhotosStorageReference = mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("photos");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               // Sign-in succeeded, set up the UI
               Toast.makeText(this, "Signed In!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
               // Sign in was canceled by the user, finish the activity
               Toast.makeText(this, "Sign In Cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               finish();
            } else if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    
               // Get a reference to store file at chat_photos/<FILENAME>
               StorageReference photoRef = 
                  mChatPhotosStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
    
               // Upload file to Firebase Storage
               photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri);
               mChatPhotosStorageReference.putFile(selectedImageUri).continueWithTask(task -> {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return mChatPhotosStorageReference.getDownloadUrl();
               }).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(null, mUsername, 
                                   downloadUri.toString());
                        mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                    }
               });
            }
       }
}[Chat Activity[After Clicking Picture icon[No response][1]
```

Comment: `push the photo to the Firebase Storage and consequently can't display in my app. ` Reading that i think: if your app has a photo then it could display it. Pretty simple task. Pushing to Firebase is a much bigger task.

Comment: [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67773610/retrieve-images-from-firebase-storage-in-form-of-arraylist-or-a-list-then-send-i/67775852#67775852)