# retrieve images from firebase storage in form of arraylist or a list then send it to firestore which later can be retrieved to populate multiple img

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

these are the references defined below;

```
StorageReference strgRef;
FirebaseFirestore mfirestore;
ArrayList<String> files,status;
List<String> downloadedimages;
RecyclerView recview;
ImageView btn_upload;
myadapter adapter;
```

I have a gallery intent followed by `activityforResults` which selects multiple images from gallery in that the code uploads the list of images selected to the `cloud firebase` storage but the I am trying to get it back in form of URIs so that i can send those URIs to make a firestore collection and then get it back from firestore to populate the imagescroll view.
`[lets take an example of a product details page of amazon where multiple images of a product are displayed that is what I am trying to achieve with the above query]`
to be noted that I want to use my mobile to upload those images.

There are no errors the chunk of code from Uri successlistener doesn't work it's neither logging the URIs fetched from firebase storage . I want to store those URIs from storage and then put it in cloud Firestore with a collection which will have those image Uri list . I am looking for a solution which will help me store these URIs into arraylist or lists which later can be sent to Firestore that's it . Thanks for reading! –

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 69 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data.getClipData() != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.getClipData().getItemCount(); i++) {

                Uri fileuri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                String filename = getfilenamefromuri(fileuri);
                files.add(filename);
                status.add("Loading");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                final int index = i;
                StorageReference upload = strgRef.child("newimages").child(filename);
                upload.putFile(fileuri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        status.remove(index);
                        status.add(index, "upload completed");
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        //uris of stored images will be added to downloadimages list
                        StorageMetadata snapshotmetadata = taskSnapshot.getMetadata();
                        Task<Uri> downloadUrl = strgRef.child("newimages").getDownloadUrl();
                        downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                while (uri != null) {
                                    final String imagesREf = uri.toString();
                                    downloadedimages.add(imagesREf);
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "images loaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.e("Firbase retrieved urls", downloadedimages.toString());
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: There are no errors the chunk of code from Uri successlistener doesn't work it's neither logging the URIs fetched from firebase storage . I want to store those URIs from storage and then put it in cloud Firestore with a collection which will have those image Uri list . I am looking for a solution which will help me store these URIs into arraylist or lists which later can be sent to Firestore that's it . Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

```
    StorageReference upload = strgRef.child("newimages").child(filename);
      upload.putFile(fileuri)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
    
                                Task<Uri> downloadUrl = strgRef.child("newimages").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                              final String imagesREf = uri.toString();
                                          
                           //here, directly store uri in firebase database or in firestore.   
                                        
                           mDatabaseRef.child("childName").setValue(imagesREf);

                          //or if you have model class use that to store in database


                                    UploaModel upload = new UploadModel("imageUrl",
                                        imagesREf);


                                    mDatabaseRef.child("childName").setValue(upload);
                                    }
                                });
    
    
    
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(UploadMake.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
```

[image]

Comment: This will put only one Uri as a string rather I want to store multiple images/Uri as a list or arraylist or string list or any way

Comment: if i make a model class can i send list of those images to database?

Comment: No you can't add all image uri in your list at once, because you can access image uri with in onSuccess() only.so instead, after upload your each image into storage, store uri in database for later access then if you want all image uri at once get it from real time database.@Sahilzilka

Comment: so what you are trying to say is that store urls in real time database rather than firestore and then extract those urls from real time database

Comment: no,you can store uri in firestore or realtime database that's your wish,but you can not use list to get all uri from firebase storage.@Sahilzilka

Answer (score 0):

The thing is to iterate through a hasp map that is to store Arraylist in a hashmap this code below is adding each image url to "savedimagesurl"

```
 private void uploadImages(View v) {
    if((imagesList.size() != 0)) {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog =new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("uplaoded 0/" + imagesList.size());
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        final StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference();
        for(int i= 0; i<imagesList.size();i++){
            final int index = i;
            storageReference.child("UserImages/").child(imagesList.get(i).getImagesName()).putFile(imagesList.get(i).getImagesUri()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                        storageReference.child("UserImages/").child(imagesList.get(index).getImagesName()).getDownloadUrl()
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>(){

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                        counter ++;
                                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded" +counter+ imagesList.size());
                                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                            savedimagesUrl.add(task.getResult().toString());
                                        }else{
                                            //this is to delete the image if the download url is not complete
                                            storageReference.child("UserImages/").child(imagesList.get(index).getImagesName()).delete();
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Could'nt save "+imagesList.get(index).getImagesName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                        if(counter == imagesList.size()){
                                            saveImageDataToFirestore(progressDialog);
                                        }

                                    }
                                });

                    }else{
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded" +counter+ "/" +imagesList.size());
                        counter++;
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "could'nt upload"+imagesList.get(index).getImagesName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }else{
        coreHelper.createSnackBar(v, "Please add some images first.", "", null, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

}
```

The function saveimageDataToFirestiore will save the images from savedimagesUrl in a hashmap to send it to firestore since the ".set" method takes hashmap as parameter

```
    private void saveImageDataToFirestore(final ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
    progressDialog.setMessage("Saving uploaded images...");
    Map<String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
    //Below line of code will put your images list as an array in fireStore
    dataMap.put("images",savedimagesUrl);

    reference.document("ImageId").set(dataMap)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    coreHelper.createAlert("Success", "Images uploaded and saved successfully!", "OK", "", null, null, null);

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            coreHelper.createAlert("Error", "Images uploaded but we couldn't save them to database.", "OK", "", null, null, null);
            Log.e("MainActivity:SaveData", e.getMessage());

        }
    });


}
```