# Hello Everyone I have a serious problem with Fireabse Firestore and the Firebase storage. Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXJW8.jpg)The problem is that I can upload users photo to my firebase storage with the current UID when they upload their own photo. but I can't retrieve it to my firebase firestore database(can't write the profile photo URL to the profile string.

I got the UID in firebase storage. but I can't write automatically it to my profile string in my firestore database.
here are the Full codes in my profile fragment. If Anyone can rewite this code for me it would be very helpful. because I manually place every Profile URL to each users profile string.

here is my code

public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

```
private  Uri imageUri;
private Bitmap compressor; // cant use it now

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


private StorageReference StorageReference;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;


public ProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

CircleImageView imageView;
FragmentProfileBinding binding;

FirebaseFirestore database;
FirebaseStorage storage;
FirebaseAuth auth;

EditText name; // name text box

User user; // user class

Button update; //update button


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    StorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("ProfilePictures");


    // to get current users full details from firebase

    imageView = binding.profileImage;
    update = binding.updateBtn;


    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            //noinspection deprecation
            startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
        }
    });



    database.collection("Users")
            .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()) // getting the unique id from database
            .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

            user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);//converting user object to class object


            binding.nameBox.setText(String.valueOf(user.getName()));
            binding.emailBox.setText(String.valueOf(user.getEmail()));

            // Glide.with(imageView)   .load(user.getProfile())   .into(binding.profileImage);
        }
    });


    return binding.getRoot();

}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data.getData() != null) {

        Uri profileUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(profileUri);


        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateUserProfile();


                progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading your cute photo..");
                progressDialog.show();

                File newFile = new File(profileUri.getPath());


                final StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("ProfilePictures")
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());

                reference.putFile(profileUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Photo Uploaded!. Play Quiz while We checking your photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }


                });



            }                            // so this is my full code in my profile fragment
                                        // you can fix or remove any code for the best output
                                        // These are my firebase firestore database //
                                        //   User > document id > "name" "profile" "email" "pass"
             });                         // profile is for profile picture

                                          // database = "ProfilePictures"
    }
}
private void updateUserProfile() {

    Uri download_uri;   // iam little bit confused here.


   download_uri = imageUri;

    Map<String, String > userdata = new HashMap<>();
    userdata.put("profile",download_uri.toString());


    firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(firebaseAuth.getUid()).set(userdata).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {


            if (task.isSuccessful()){



                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Succesful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }else {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Firestore Error:"  +task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });                   //whenever I run the app, if I click the 
                          upload button the app is closing. also not 
                          storing it to storage, and not retrieve to 
                          firestore database 

}
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this code?

Comment: Look at here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67773610/retrieve-images-from-firebase-storage-in-form-of-arraylist-or-a-list-then-send-i/67775852#67775852)

Comment: Hello Alex mamo. the problem is i cant upload the user image to the firebase storage, and also cant retrieve it to my firebase firestore database. if you could help me, I can share my Fragment and the layout XML with you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. but I have another error. when I upload the image URI to the firebase firestore database, the other data were gone and only the profile URI is visible.

currently, i have 5 strings
name
email
password
profile(image URI)
refer id
coins

but,  when a user uploads their profile photo. all data were removed.

showing only the profile image URI

I have attached the code here

private void updateUserProfile() {

```
    Map<String,String > profile = new HashMap<>();
    profile.put("profile",imageUri.toString());



    database
            .collection("Users") // the path of users.
            .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()) // to update in the current users.
        //    .update(user)
            .set(profile)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {

                 Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Photo Updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  

                }
            });



}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not about the issue that you described in the comment;
If you want to amend/update only one field you can use the update method instead of `set` method. If you use `set` method alone without defining the merge option, the document will overwrite.

So the code should write as;

```
database.collection("Users") // the path of users.
            .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
            .update("profile",imageUri.toString())
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Profile Image path successfully updated!");
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error updating Profile Image path", e);
            }
        });
```